# HtmlAgilityPack: How can i remove a tag from an node while i'am looping through the node collection?

Tags: asp.net, tags, html-agility-pack

How can i remove a tag from an node while i'am looping through the node collection

I'am in the loop though a complex document with

```
For Each node As HtmlNode In document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//section/div[3]/section/article")
```

then i get an address string which i split  in this way

```
adress = Split(node.SelectSingleNode("./div[2]/div").InnerHtml, "<br>")
```

But sometimes i have some advertising in this adress which is coming from a tooltip which always starts with a "span" Tag
How can i remove this before i split the result from the node?

example befor i split the  result looks normaly

```
88989 <br> myCity <br> mySTreet <br> address
```

in some cases the result looks like

```
88989 <br> myCity <span>mycity is a nice city<br> Visit us </span> <br> mySTreet <br> address
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, got it to work with

```
 Dim ChildNode As HtmlNode
 For Each node As HtmlNode In document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//section/div[3]/section/article")
   Dim code = ChildNode.SelectSingleNode("./span")
   ChildNode.RemoveChild(code, False)
...
```